# Using property file values in Hazelcast XML config

Tags: java, xml, properties, hazelcast

Is it possible to load the property file values in `hazelcast.xml`.

Example :
In `hazelcast.xml` file,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/home/local/Documents/testproperty/test.properties"/>
```

Loading property file using the above tag and use the property value in the hazelcast xml as below,

```
<properties>
<property name="hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds" value = "${HAZELCAST_MAX_NO_HEARTBEAT_SECONDS}"></property>
<property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout" value = "${HAZELCAST_CLIENT_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT}"></property>
```

Is there any other way to load the property values inside the xml?

**NOTE :** Loaded into the application using 
Config cfg = new XmlConfigBuilder(xmlFileName).build();

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Not 100% sure about our implementation but did you try the default property replacement strategy for Hazelcast? http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#using-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harry,

Here is how you can do that

```
// our you can inject this using Spring   
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(CurrentClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hazelcast.properties"));

final Config config = new XmlConfigBuilder("hazelcast-with-properties.xml")
        .setProperties(properties) // this is how you can set the properties 
        .build();

final HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

hazelcast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
       xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config">
   <properties>
     <!-- pay attention to the format - property tag doesn't have value attribute -->
     <property name="hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds">${HAZELCAST_MAX_NO_HEARTBEAT_SECONDS}</property>
     <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout">${HAZELCAST_CLIENT_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT}</property>
     <property name="hazelcast.backpressure.enabled">${HAZELCAST_BACKPRESSURE_ENABLED}</property>
  </properties>
  <group>
      <name>${group.name}</name>
      <password>${group.password}</password>
  </group>
</hazelcast>
```

`hazelcast.properties`

```
group.name=devFromProp
group.password=supA$ecret42
HAZELCAST_MAX_NO_HEARTBEAT_SECONDS=5
HAZELCAST_CLIENT_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT=500
HAZELCAST_BACKPRESSURE_ENABLED=true
```

That should do the thing.

Thank you

Comment: Even we tried with FileSystemConfig, properties too, It works like a fly. Do we have the same option for client config?

Comment: I don't have client's java doc in front of my eyes right now but, I'm pretty sure you can the same with Java client XML config